# Dirac delta of exponential function

Tags: functions, roots, dirac-delta

I couldn't find this very problem anywhere, albeit looking for an hour now...

Simple question: What is $\int \mathrm{d}x f(x) \delta(\mathrm{e}^x)$?

$f(x)$ is any suitable function.

Mathematica spits out zero, but I don't understand why, since $\mathrm{e}^x$ has no zero and hence the usual formula for functions as delta arguments $\delta(g(x)) = \sum_i \frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|g'(x_i)|}$ [where $x_i$ are zeros of $g(x)$] doesn't work.

I tried to substitute the argument of the delta $\mathrm{e}^x = y$, tried to add an infinitesimal $\epsilon$ in the argument, to get $\delta(\mathrm{e}^x-\epsilon)$ or tried to write the delta as a delta sequence $\delta(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \delta_\epsilon(x)$ and to take the limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ at the end of the calculation.

Nothing worked for me, to show, that the above integral is zero.

Comment: Since $e^x$ has no zeros for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $\delta(e^x)$ evaluates to zero for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and hence the integral $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \delta\left(e^x\right)\, f(x)\, dx$ also evaluates to zero.

Comment: The sum formula actually works because an empty sum evaluates to zero.

Comment: I don't think, that works. The sum formula is just the result, which you get, when substituting $g(x)$ by some $y$. The result in this case is, that you get something like $... \delta(y)/y$ in the integrand.

Comment: The sum is over the real zeros of $g(x)$ , so if there are no real zeros of $g(x)$ which is the case for $g(x)=e^x$, the sum is empty and correctly evaluates to zero. The sum $\sum\limits_{x\in S} a(x)$ for some set $S$ is zero when $S$ is the empty set regardless of the definition of the function $a(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first make up your mind what the expression means.  A distribution is a functional on $C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R})$ and a tempered distribution is a functional on $\Bbb{S}(\Bbb{R})$ (the Schwartz space).

If you make a change of variable $x=\ln y$ then
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \text{d}x f(x) \delta(e^x) = \int_0^{+\infty} \text{d}y \frac{f(\ln y)}{y} \delta(y)$$
and presumably the intent is that this last integral is
$$\lim_{y\searrow 0} \frac{f(\ln y)}{y} = \lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} e^{-x} f(x)$$

Now, if $f\in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R})$ then this limit is zero, because there's an $N\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = 0$ for $x<N$.

However, if $f\in\Bbb{S}(\Bbb{R})$, this limit may not exist - because Schwartz functions f are guaranteed to have $|x|^k f(x)$ bounded for all $k>0$, but $e^{-x}$ does not fit within such a bound as $x\rightarrow -\infty$.  So the expression is not well-defined for Schwartz functions and is not a tempered distribution.  Informally it's because the growth of $\delta(e^x)$ is faster than any polynomial as $x\rightarrow -\infty$.

Comment: And $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is the space of smooth functions with compact support? Then I do understand your answer and it sounds very logic to me, thank you!

Comment: But is it correct, to evaluate the delta function at $y = 0$, if the integral starts at $y = 0$?

Comment: Also let's look at $f(x) = \mathrm{e}^x$. Then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{e}^x \, \delta(\mathrm{e}^x)$ evaluates to one according to your above solution, right? But shouldn't we expect, that this integral is zero?